# How to redirect output of ksh -x to a file in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

I have been using ksh -x myscript to debug my shell script.
I got some errors. Now I need to send these lines that are produced by ksh -x.
I tried ksh -x myscript > temp.txt.

It is not redirecting to the file. How to redirect the ksh -x line by line excecution into a file?

Comment: Try `ksh -x script 2> file` or `ksh -x script > file 2>&1`

Comment: Thanks. ksh -x script 2 >file works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not happening probably because the simple redirection just redirect the stdout to the file . The statement written in the script which are written as to be displayed in stdout will be captured when  `ksh -x myscript > temp.txt`  is done .. the debug information is not the part of stdout 
if you just want to capture just the debug statement you should use

`ksh -x myscript 2> temp.txt` 
or in other way you can combine the output as well as debug( stdout and stderr) to be redirected at same place like 
this
`ksh -x myscript 2>&1  temp.txt`